# Dynamically adding Metro JS Tiles with Javascript

Tags: javascript, html

I have a blog that I am using metro js on

[My blog](http://www.AnthonyRussell.info)

[Metro JS](http://www.drewgreenwell.com/projects/metrojs)

I am attempting to put a button at the bottom of the page that will load 5 posts at a time.

Everything was going swimmingly until I attempted to dynamically load Metro.js tiles.

The javascript function below is just a demo. I planned on doing an ajax call but I cant even get the demo working yet.

what loads on start

```
<div  class="tiles">
  <div id="id#" class="live-tile four-wide" data-mode="none" data-bounce="true">
    <div style="background-color:orange;">
     <table><tr><td><img src="textsym.png" width="50"/></td>
       <td><h1>title</h1></td></tr> 
     </table>
   </div>
 </div>
</div>
```

This is what I tried

```
 function loadmore() {
            var tiles = document.getElementById("tiles").innerHTML;

            tiles = tiles + "<div class=\"tiles\"><div id=\"\" class=\"live-tile four-wide\" data-mode=\"none\" data-bounce=\"true\"><div style=\"background-color:orange;\"><table><tr><td><img src=\"textsym.png\" width=\"50\"/></td><td><h1>title</h1></td></tr> </table></div></div>";
            document.getElementById("tiles").innerHTML = tiles;
        }
```

The problem is that it is adding the tile but it isn't making it clickable like the other tiles. Is there something I am missing?

Answer (score 0):

So the answer to this question is pretty easy

The JS file needs to be told that there are new elements on the page.

When the page is loaded initially, according to the metro js documentation, you run this JQuery Function

```
$(".live-tile").liveTile({
    click: function ($tile, tileData) {
        var id = $tile.attr("id");
        window.location = "postpage.php?name=" + id;
        return false; // or return true; 
    }
});
```

As far as I can tell this some how ties the class live-tile to the click handler that I have here. postpage.php....

So all I did was add this JQuery call into my button click function above. This refreshes the page and makes everything work.

```
function loadmore() {
      var tiles = document.getElementById("tiles").innerHTML;

        tiles = tiles + "<div class=\"tiles\"><div id=\"\" class=\"live-tile four-wide\" data-mode=\"none\" data-bounce=\"true\"><div style=\"background-color:orange;\"><table><tr><td><img src=\"textsym.png\" width=\"50\"/></td><td><h1>title</h1></td></tr> </table></div></div>";
        document.getElementById("tiles").innerHTML = tiles;

        $(".live-tile").liveTile({
            click: function ($tile, tileData) {
                var id = $tile.attr("id");
                window.location = "postpage.php?name=" + id;
                return false; // or return true; 
            }
        });

        }
```